# haskell happy - "Couldn't match expected type"

Tags: parsing, haskell, parser-generator, happy

I have some problems to understand error messages of the parser generator system happy for haskell.

For instance this code

```
{
module Test_parser where

import System.IO
import Test_lexer

}

%name parse

%tokentype { Token }
%error { parseError }

%token

    true                { TokenTrue posn }
    false               { TokenFalse posn }
    number              { TokenInteger posn $$ }

%%

LiteralExpr :
        true            {LiteralTrue ()}
    | false         {LiteralFalse ()}
    | number        {LiteralInteger () $1}

{

data Expression n =
    LiteralTrue n
    | LiteralFalse n
    | LiteralInteger n Integer
        deriving (Eq, Show)

parseError xs = error "Parse error"

main = do 
  inStr <- getContents
  let parseTree = parse (alexScanTokens inStr)  
  putStrLn $ show(parseTree)
}
```

works fine.

But if I do something like that

```
....

LiteralExpr :
    true            {LiteralTrue ()}
    | false         {LiteralFalse ()}
    | Inte          {$1}

Inte :
    number          {LiteralInteger () $1}


{

data Expression n =
    LiteralTrue n
    | LiteralFalse n
    | Inte n
        deriving (Eq, Show)

data Inte n =
    LiteralInteger n Integer
        deriving (Eq, Show)

....
```

I will get a huge error message.
So it would be very nice if you could help me to understand it.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you're confusing data constructors and type constructors. `Inte` in `Expression` is a data constructor that happened to have the same name as (and isn't otherwise related to) the `Inte` datatype that you define below.

You should have something like

```
data Expression n =
    LiteralTrue n
    | LiteralFalse n
    | LiteralInt (Inte n)
```

and modify your code appropriately (add `LiteralInt` where needed).

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Maybe you are right but I still get error messages. This does not work :".. LiteralExpr :
 true    {LiteralTrue ()}
 | false   {LiteralFalse ()}
 | Inte   {LiteralInt (Inte () $1)}

Inte :
 number   {LiteralInteger () $1}


{

data Expression n =
 LiteralTrue n
 | LiteralFalse n
 | LiteralInt (Inte n)
  deriving (Eq, Show)

data Inte n =
 LiteralInteger n Integer
  deriving (Eq, Show) .." Could you please modify the given code example to run it. Maybe I get it after seeing the correct version. ;)

Answer (score 0):

ok, this is the way it goes:

```
...
LiteralExpr :
    true            {LiteralTrue ()}
    | false         {LiteralFalse ()}
    | Inte          {LiteralInt $1}

Inte :
    number          {LiteralInteger () $1}
...
```

and

```
...
data Expression n =
    LiteralTrue n
    | LiteralFalse n
    | LiteralInt (Inte n)
        deriving (Eq, Show)

data Inte n =
    LiteralInteger n Integer
        deriving (Eq, Show)
...
```